# If there is a way to specifiy a custom ServiceHost (i.e. a ServiceHost derived class) in configuration?

Tags: c#, wcf

If there is a way to specifiy a custom ServiceHost (i.e. a ServiceHost derived class) or custom ServiceHostFactory (i.e. a ServiceHostFactory derived class) via configuration?

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either you use IIS for hosting your WCF service - in that case, you can specify a custom service host factory (which creates your custom `ServiceHost` instance) in your `*.svc` file:

```
<%@ServiceHost Factory="CustomServiceHostFactory" language=c# Debug="true" 
               Service="MyService, MyServiceAssembly"  %>
```

or then you're self-hosting, so you need to create the `ServiceHost` in your code anyway, so just use your own custom service host instead.

```
MyCustomServiceHost host = new MyCustomServiceHost();

// do other initialization / setup stuff
host.Open();
```

Comment: I dont use hosting in IIS. I need it for visual studio WCF Service Host utility, which reads configuration from *.config file

Comment: @VoimiX: I highly doubt you'll be able to get the WCF Service Host utiltiy to use a custom service host - probably have to write your own

Answer (score 0):

You might find useful Spring's implementation, at least to see how they implemented their custom ServiceHost and Factory (here is the doc link: http://www.springframework.net/doc-latest/reference/html/wcf.html)